# Problems with Enemy AI

Tags: game-engine

I am developing a simple ball game, where the sole objective is "Survive as long as you can from the enemy balls". So I gave my ball controls and set the enemy ball's AI to "path following". It seemed to work flawlessly, but now I am facing a problem where the enemy balls get stuck behind a wall and. You can understand the problem better by seeing this image,

[image: Enemy AI- Problems]
Note: Red ball - Player, White balls - enemies

I tried to changing the game environment, set the enemy AI to "seek". But none of them worked.

So, How do I rectify this problem? Also, is there a way not to make the enemy balls come together as in the image?

Comment: I suggest to enable Visualize at the Steering Actuator. It will show you what path the object wants to go.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with your navigation mesh. Make sure the navmesh is going around the wall. If it isn't you can punch a hole in it in edit mode, then reset index values in the Physics tab, and set Visualize on in the actuator to make sure it works. Hope this helps! If it doesn't you may want to check the navmesh normal up direction (It's the small "N" checkbox beside the up-direction listbox.)